# messy code emerge after unicode translating into stata14 format

Tags: stata

My dataset contains a string variable where some “exotic character” exist, which means you can’t eliminate some blank spaces around the string. Following [this thread](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2005-04/msg00891.html) in statalist, I have managed to identify and remove those unobservable exotic characters (though not quite understand the underlying mechanism).

```
. charlist city

 &'().01?ABCDEGHIJKLMNPQSTUWXYZabcdeghijklnopqrstuwxyz?

. ret li

macros:
              r(chars) : "

 &'().01?ABCDEGHIJKLMNPQSTUWXYZabcdeghijklnopqrs.."
           r(sepchars) : "

   & ' ( ) . 0 1 ? A B C D E G H I J K L M N P .."
              r(ascii) : "10 13 32 38 39 40 41 46 48 49 63 65 66 67 68 69 71.."
```

and

```
replace city = subinstr(city, "`=char(10)'", "",.)
replace city = subinstr(city, "`=char(32)'", "",.)
replace city = subinstr(city, "`=char(161)'`=char(161)'", "",.)
```

However, when I want to convert this dataset（of Stata13 format）to Stata 14 format using Unicode command, the string variable is replaced by those little square like following. Even I keep the original variable without removing the exotic characters, it still end up with the same result. So that I'm not 100% sure whether it's due to encoding problem or the exotic characters

The unicode translate is preformed like

```
cd E:\Land_Supply\Data\土地交易微观数据
clear
*unicode encoding set gb18030 // city names are in chinese
unicode analyze trans_citypanel2013.dta
unicode translate trans_citypanel2013.dta,invalid
u trans_citypanel2013,clear
```

[image]

Comment: Does everything look OK with Stata 13? In other words, does the problem only appear after translating and opening the file with Stata 14?

Comment: @ChrisP, Yeap, exactly the same. So I highly suspect if the `unicode translate` command worked at all. Unfortunately, I could not update the data sample as attactment in stockoverflow

Comment: Maybe check that the font you're using in Stata actually has the characters you are trying to display (do this in Stata's preferences). You could put a sample of the data online and link to it in your post.

Comment: Thanks for your kindly reply. I have also posted on statalist on which there is a data sample attachment.

Comment: Thanks for your kindly reply. I have also posted on statalist on which there is a data sample attachment.

Comment: https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1406515-failed-to-unicode-translate-the-chinese-character-string-to-stata14-format

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work for me using your example data...

```
unicode analyze citynames.dta
unicode encoding set gb18030
unicode translate citynames.dta
use citynames.dta, clear
list in 1/3

     +------------+
     |       city |
     |------------|
  1. | 　阿尔山市  |
  2. | 　阿尔山市  |
  3. | 　阿尔山市  |
     +------------+
```

I don't read Chinese, so maybe that's gibberish, but it looks like it worked to me. If those names don't make sense, try another encoding.